# Dynamically find pieces of phrase in string using regex and .replace()

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a large string I need to removed the phrase "Pages 1 of 3 Printed on:" and I'm trying to use regex to make the 1 of X to be dynamic. I've also tried using the wildcard and string template, but I'm having no luck.

I currently have it working hard coded. For example, if I hard code 3, it will find the entire phrase, replace it with nothing, and find any other instances. Any help is appreciated!

```
let text = 'Pages 1 of 3 Printed on: FIRST NAME Pages 2 of 3 Printed on: TITLE SIGNATURE Pages 3 of 3 Printed on: STAN SMITH'


// Remove Pages
if (text('Pages 1 of ' + /[0-9]/ + 'Printed on: ')) {
    // Removing Begins
    console.log('Removing: Pages 1 of ' + /[0-9]/ + 'Printed on: ');

    // Remove Text
    text = text('Pages 1 of ' + /[0-9]/ + 'Printed on: ', '');

    // Find Any Other Instances Of Text
    while (text.includes('Pages 1 of /[1-9]/gPrinted on: ', '')) {
        text = text('Pages 1 of ' + /[0-9]/ + 'Printed on: ', '', '');
    }

    // Removing Ends
    console.log('Removed: Pages 1 of ' + /[0-9]/ + 'Printed on: ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the (global) regular expression:

```
/Pages \d+ of \d+ Printed on: /g
```

```js
let text = 'Pages 1 of 3 Printed on: FIRST NAME Pages 2 of 3 Printed on: TITLE SIGNATURE Pages 3 of 3 Printed on: STAN SMITH';
const output = text.replace(/Pages \d+ of \d+ Printed on: /g, '');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: The "regular expression" concept is a new one for me, so thank you!

Comment: When an answer solves the problem you're having, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely what the rest of the code looks like, but if you want to print 1 of X with incrementing value of X, you could do:

`` for (let i in pages) console.log(`Printing page ${i+1} of ${pages}`); ``

This is if `pages` is an int.